# Iterate over all current sessions in django

Tags: python, django, session

Is it possible in django to iterate all current sessions? I want to implement a calendar where it is impossible to book a timeslot that someone else is booking. I Keep a list of timeslots id's in the session before the user proceeds to checkout.

Comment: How do you identify "current" sessions?

Comment: All session data that exists for users at a given moment? What would be the better way to describe this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you can't. You need to implement some kind of time-limited reservation. Temporarily book a timeslot for user on his second booking step - right after he picks his date. Then if he finalizes the process make the book permanent or delete reservation (and make the date available again) after few minutes.

You need to do this in this way, otherwise you will end up with lots of dead dates created by users which didn't finish the booking process.

Answer (score 0):

`def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):`

```
for r in request.session.items():
     print(r)
```

[read here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.items)

Comment: Cheers for stepping-up to provide an answer. As a new poster, please be aware SO answers are generally improved by including a short in-line explanation (in addition to link and code).